# Fetching my location with setMyLocationEnabled() method

Tags: android

I am trying to get my location in a map using the `setMyLocationEnabled()` method. There is no problem with this method, I have also used `setMyLocationButtonEnabled()` and everything is good.

But when I click on the button in the map, I don't get the "blue dot" that indicates my location.

Can you tell me what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0):

The setMyLocationEnable won't work alone. you have to put requestLocationUpdates in the onResume.

```
      @Override
  public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (isGPSEnabled) {
        locMgr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, time, distance, this);
        }
        if (isNetworkEnabled) {
            locMgr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, time, distance, this);
        }

    map.setLocationSource(this);

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should either declare an anonymous inner class, that implements `Google.OnMyLocationChangeListener`, or you could just implement it in your main class. Let's say the instance of your map is called `map`. You will have to set the listener, like this: `map.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(this)`. Then, you will have to do something like this:

```
@Override
public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) //inherited from the interface you implemented
{
//do your thing, the variable "location" holds everything you need
}
```